# headers - spel to split the string

Tags: spring-integration, spring-el

I have to split the string present in the headers.

```
<int:header name="plans-array" expression="headers['plans'].split(',')"/>
```

How to make this String array into List like the below one which converts the list automatically.

```
 @Value("#{'${plans}'.split(',')}") 
 private List<String> myList;
```

I tried like below but is not working correctly.

```
<int:header name="plans-list" expression="T(java.util.Arrays).asList(headers['plans'].split(','))"/>
```

integration xml

```
<int:channel id="splitChannel"/>
<int:header-enricher input-channel="splitChannel">
    <int:header name="isPlanExist" expression="T(java.util.Arrays).asList((headers['plans'].split(','))).contains('plan1')"/>
</int:header-enricher>
```

JUnit

```
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("splitChannel")
    private MessageChannel splitChannel;

    @Test
    public void testSplit() {

String somePayload = "somePayload";
Message<String> stringPayload = MessageBuilder.withPayload(somePayload)
    .setHeader("plans", "plan1,plan2")
    .build();

MessagingTemplate template = new MessagingTemplate();
Assert.assertEquals(true, template.sendAndReceive(this.splitChannel, stringPayload).getHeaders().get("isPlanExist"));
```

Comment: This works fine and plans-array have String[] but just getting the error mentioned above in the debug mode.

Comment: What is `debug mode`? How can we reproduce it locally? Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the late response Artem. I meant debugging logs. I am getting the array of String after split with comma seperated. Please suggest the solution for the edited question.

Comment: Well, are you spy? Why don't tell or show how does it work? And what is the problem live with array and convert it into list somewhere downstream already in Java code?

Comment: we can convert it in the donwstream, but just checking the feasibiltiy in integration without java code for few lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good, now I see your problem.

You have code like `T(java.util.Arrays).asList((headers['plans'].split(',')))`

In Java it works fine because compiler treat one argument with array type as a varargs.

Here we have a SpEL, which in most case is based on the reflection method invocation. So, there is no compiler optimization and we end up with the fact of `List<String[]>` with one element, not like you expect `List<String>` with two elements.

I wouldn't say that it is a SpEL problem. That is how Java reflection works here.

To fix your problem you should consider to use some other `array -> list` utility to bypass varargs issue, e.g.:

```
T(org.springframework.util.CollectionUtils).arrayToList(headers['plans'].split(',')).contains('plan1')
```

Comment: Got it..works perfectly!! Really sorry about that if my question confuses you.